# Replacing a word in a string by another word with MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, mips

I am trying to make a MIPS function that takes 3 string parameters, txt1, txt2, and txt3, and replaces any occurrence of the txt1 in txt3 with txt2. For the moment I am only able to do it with txt1 and txt2 being single characters, how could I do it with words?

Example of what I am trying to make:
Inp: txt1, txt2, txt3 = xx, yy, XXxx;
Out: XXyy

Here is what I made:

```
    la $a0,string #load address of string
    lb $a1,orig   #load original character
    lb $a2,new    #load new character
    li $a3,0      #load replace with zero first
    li $t0,0      #load index
    loop:
    lb $t0,0($a0) #load character
    beqz $t0,exit #exit when loop finish

    bne $t0,$a1,skip #compare with original character
    sb $a2,0($a0)    #replace character
    add $a3,$a3,1    #increase replace count by one
    skip:
    add $a0,$a0,1    #increase count by one
    j loop
    exit:

    end:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,rprompt
    syscall
```

Would really appreciate any sort of help!!

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once: writing assembly is really hard when you don't know the language and also don't have an algorithm to tell you what steps will get the job done.  Algorithms are language independent.  That's good news because (a) you don't have to think in MIPS assembly to create an algorithm, and (b) you can search for and speak about such algorithm independently of MIPS assembly language, and (c) you can create the algorithm in a language you know.

Comment: Translating a working algorithm into assembly is very manageable.  For one, you can ask / search on how to translate C language constructs to assembly independent of your algorithm.  For another, if there's problems, they at least won't be algorithmic problems if you start with working algorithm; that's good b/c debugging a broken algorithm in assembly is painful.

Comment: Unavoidably you're going to have to match each letter of the word. Once the first letter matches, remember where in the string it was, and then keep checking for a full match. This gets tricky when the replacement word isn't the same size as the word you're trying to find.